Why is this local chart on a fibre bundle $(E, M, \pi, L)$ compatible with the given smooth structure on $E$?
In these lecture notes, at Remark 16.5, Merry states:
''Suppose $(W, \varepsilon)$ is a bundle chart on $E$. Let $(U, x)$ and $(V, y)$ be (manifold) charts on $M$ and $L$ respectively with $W \subset U$.
Then $(x \circ \pi, y \circ \varepsilon)$ is a manifold chart on an open set in $E$ which is compatible with the given smooth structure on $E$.''
I understand that $(x \circ \pi, y \circ \varepsilon)$ is a manifold chart on an open set in $E$ but I do not understand how to show that it is compatible with the given smooth structure on $E$.
I would like to show that for any local chart $(S, z)$ on $E$, if $S$ has nonempty intersection with the domain of $(x \circ \pi, y \circ \varepsilon)$, then the transition map $ (x \circ \pi, y \circ \varepsilon) \circ z^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism. How do I write such transition map?
Is there another way to show that $(x \circ \pi, y \circ \varepsilon)$ is compatible with the given smooth structure on $E$?

This is basically because you assume that $\epsilon$ is a diffeomorphism using that the composition of diffeomorphisms is a diffeomorphism. There is no need to check compatibility with other local charts on $E$.

Thank you for your help. If I understand correctly, it is not possible to prove or argue that the local chart $(x \circ \pi, y \circ \varepsilon)$ is compatible with the smooth structure on $E$. We need $E$ to be a smooth manifold in order to assert, in the definition of a fibre bundle, that the map $\pi$ is smooth. However, to work with the local chart $(x \circ \pi, y \circ \varepsilon)$, and the preferred coordinate representation that it induces, we create a new atlas on $E$.

I'll address this in an answer

The definition of a fiber bundle chart in the notes you link to says that $(\epsilon,\pi):\pi^{-1}(W)\to W\times L$ is a diffeomorphism and my comment was intending to say that this is the key to compatibility. More explicitly taking charts $(U,x)$ and $(V,y)$ as in your question, it is a standard result that $(U\times V,u\times v)$ is a chart on $M\times L$. Hence given any chart $(Z,z)$ on $E$ such that $Z\cap W\neq\emptyset$, smoothness of $(\epsilon,\pi)$ says that the composition $(x,y)\circ (\epsilon,\pi) \circ z^{-1}=(x\circ\epsilon,y\circ\pi)\circ z$ is smooth on $z(Z\cap W)$. This is exactly one direction of the compatibility condition between $(Z,z)$ and $(W,x\circ\epsilon,y\circ\pi)$. The other direction similarly follows using smoothness of the inverse of $(\epsilon,\pi)$.
